# In what order are SQL Server child tables deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, cascade

Consider the following database diagram, consisting of a parent table with three child tables:

[image: Basic Tables]

Assume that the child tables have FKs to "Account" via "AccountID" with cascading delete enabled - so if I delete an Account record, it should delete its child records.

My question is simple: in SQL Server, is there any particular order that the child tables will be deleted?

Comment: You must have enabled cascaded delete on your foreign keys as they won't delete child records by default. AFAIK there is no defined order that they will be deleted - does it matter?

Comment: @chakeda You don't `delete` tables, you `drop` them. I believe you are referring to `deleting` a parent table `record` and consequently related child `records`?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @RyanWilson - yes, I meant deleting an `Account` record instead dropping a table. @Dale K - yes, assume ONDELETE=CASCADE. The defined order is my big question.

Comment: @chakeda I don't know if there is a specific order in which they are deleted, you could add triggers to the tables and do an insert on delete trigger into a table to record which table had the deletion take place, that way you could compare deletion order. This would take a few trial runs, but should give you an idea of whether it always follows the same deletion order.

Comment: I've updated the question for the clarifications. @RyanWilson - hmm I could give that a shot. I am hoping I can find some official documentation on this though.

Comment: You'd be better off posting at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ as they are DB experts, we're just devs here.

Comment: @chakeda I've looked over a few docs on Cascading Delete but haven't found anything as of yet which clearly states an answer to your question. Perhaps someone else will be able to give you a concise answer.

Comment: Order is neither documented nor guaranteed. I'll repeat what someone else asked, _why does it matter_? If it matters for some reason, just don't use cascade (that's my advice in general, anyway). If you use triggers (or force deletes through a stored procedure), you can explicitly control everything.

Comment: I should have clarified the order does matter - we're considering something like adding a table connecting Item & Stats or creating triggers that would affect siblings. This answers my question - I'll have to remove the cascade and do it on the code end. I'll accept any answer that says this.